# maven javadoc plugin throwing exception Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - cannot read Input length = 1

Tags: maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

maven jaavadoc plugin generates argument files: options and packages, but when javadoc is executed through this plugin following error appears:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - cannot read Input length = 1

Answer (score 0):

it was an issue in encoding, in maven-javadoc-plugin encoding was specified as utf-8 while one of the property file was having a character in ISO-8859-1 format. Fixed it by replacing the given character in appropriate format.